# Why compiler gives .NullPointerException error

Tags: java

Whenever I compile the below code, it gives the `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. I have looked my code but it seems correct. Is it compiler broken or Did I miss something?

```
 public byte[][] divi(byte[] pac, int pac_len){
      int set = 0 ;
      byte [][] data = null;

      for( int i= 0 ; set != pac_len; i++) { 
           if (set + 33 <= pac_len) {
                data[i] = new byte[33];
                System.arraycopy(pac, set, data[i], 0, 33);
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: NullPointerException is a runtime exception, you cannot get it during compilation.

Comment: Is there a compiletime exception ?

Comment: If what you say is true, you have uncovered an extremely rare compiler bug. and you should report it on the Java Bug Parade. More likely you are just misusing terminology. Editing the stack trace into your question would resolve that one way or the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you missed something: the assignment

```
byte [][] data = null;
```

clearly assigns `null` to `data`. After that, you make assignments to `data[i]`, which causes `NullPointerException`.

Rewriting the above line as

```
byte [][] data = new byte[][pac_len];
```

should fix the `NPE` problem.

It wouldn't fix the infinite loop problem - you need to adjust your `set` variable for that. Currently, `set` does not change, so the loop is infinite. It looks like your code is trying to parcel out a long array into 33-byte chunks. You need to take special care of the case when `pac_len` is not divisible by 33, because the loop condition requires `set` to be exactly `pac_len` in order to exit.

Answer (score 1):

First, `NPE` is a *runtime-exception*, you won't get it in a compilation time.

Second, you assign `null` to `data` and then you try to access it. Which is `NPE` of course.

Third, after you fixed the two problems mentioned above, you should fix your loop: `for( int i= 0 ; set != pac_len; i++)`

Your condition is not good in this loop. `i` might exceed the array bounds which may cause you an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`, you should make sure that `i` never exceeds the length of the array (Your loop is infinite..)